# Help needed in using escape function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the follwing javascript function in my jsp file

```
 <script language="javascript">

                    function openPopup()
                    {
                        var firstname = escape(<%=addressBean.getFirstName()%>);
                        var lastname = escape(<%=addressBean.getLastName()%>);
                        alert(firstname);
                        alert(lastname);
                        var mywindow = window.open('<%= link("*", "BBFBUpdatePickupInfo")%>&ShoppingCartKey=<%=cartKey%>&operation=<%=operation%>&isEproAcc=<%=isEpro%>&firstName="+firstname+"&lastName="+lastname+"&areaCode=<%=addressBean.getPhoneAreaCode()%>&phoneNum=<%=addressBean.getPhoneNumber()%>','static','width=625,height=500,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=yes,resizable=0');
                        mywindow.focus();
                    }


                </script>
```

When addressBean.getFirstName() and addressBean.getLastName() returns names like "RED" as firstname and "WHITE" as lastname it is working fine. But when these two methods returns name like "VALENTINE" as firstname and "D'LOREY" as second name it is throwing below javascript error

```
  Error: Unterminated string constant
  Code: 0
```

Please help me to come out of this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: `escape` is deprecated because it doesn't support UTF-8. Use `encodeURIComponent` instead.

Comment: `escape` has issues. Don't use it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Predefined_Functions/escape_and_unescape_Functions for details.

Comment: i have used encodeURIComponent instead of escape but the problem exists...

Comment: @raja: Right, because that issue is off-topic (but still useful).

Comment: So what is the solution for that problem?

Comment: I have read it in one article that "encodeURIComponent() will not encode: ~!*()' ".

Comment: @raja - You have two answers, and I know one of them was there at the time I made my previous comment. Look to answers for answers to your question, and comments for comments (which could help you in other ways).

Comment: @raja — Those characters don't need encoding in URIs.

Answer (score 3):

(You haven't mentioned what your server-side language is; below I've assumed Java, so make adjustments if it's something else.)

Think about what's actually getting sent to the browser when you do this:

```
var firstname = escape(<%=addressBean.getFirstName()%>);
```

When it goes out, it'll look like this:

```
var firstname = escape(JOE);
```

...which is almost certainly not what you want -- there are no quotes, for a start.

So first we need quotes:

```
var firstname = escape("<%=addressBean.getFirstName()%>");
```

But we also need to escape anything in the string that's going to be an issue in the resulting JavaScript string (on the server, when sending it to the browser). Off the cuff, that'll be at least quotes and backslashes, so:

```
var firstname = escape("<%=addressBean.getFirstName().replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"", "\\\"")%>");
```

...but that's not thorough at all, you'll need to handle lots of other cases (newlines in the string, etc.). Really, you're going to want a utility function that does the work thoroughly, handling (for instance) unicode sequences, etc., if there's any possibility they'll be in the source data (which there very much is, if this involves people's names).

And many have noted that instead of `escape`, you want `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: As other commenters have said, use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `escape`.

Comment: i have used encodeURIComponent instead of escape but the problem exists

Comment: @raja: `encodeURIComponent` is featured in exactly one sentence of my answer. Did you read the **rest** of it?

Comment: @raja - That is in addition to the fixes described in the answer, no instead.

Comment: @Crowder, I read all other content also. But the fact is, the special character in the name vary dynamically. So i cant the particular special character in the code. One more thing i read out in the article is encodeURIComponent will not encode ~!*()'

Comment: this won't work because he needs to escape on the SERVER side first.

Comment: @Mike: That's **exactly** what I'm telling him to do. The bits within `<%` and `%>` are server-side in JSP pages (and most other server-side templating systems, like ASP and such).

Comment: @raja: The characters that need to be escaped are well-defined, just write (or locate) a function to do it. Fundamentally, the point is that you need to think about *what you're sending to the browser* and make sure that that's valid JavaScript. So that means putting quotes around the string content, escaping anything in the content that will mess things up (like other quotes, newlines, etc.). At the very least you need to handle quotes, backslashes, backspaces, newlines, carriage returns, and formfeeds. And you'll probably want to use unicode escape sequences for anything that isn't ASCII.

Comment: sorry, TJ. I haven't had my coffee yet this morning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly format your string so that it is compatible with JavaScript syntax in variables definition.

This is what I do with PHP through the `json_encode()` function:

```
var firstname = <?=json_encode(addressBean.getFirstName())?>;
```

The JSON parser takes care of escaping the appropriate values and makes it JavaScript compatible.

I'm not familiar with your language, but if it's ASP you can try out [aspjson](http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/).

Comment: *"You need to JSON encode your variable"* No, he doesn't. He just needs to send a properly-formatted string. Although actually, if he has a JSON encoder lying around, that might be a really convenient way to do it.

Comment: @Crowder: Yes, that was badly written.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and Javascript are 2 escapes. I had this problem and nonscientifically just observed switch (too fast) from georss to KML just solved

Answer (score 0):

Just create the url server-side since it is made of server-side variables. No need to do it with strings and escapes in javascript when you have everything at hand server-side.